# How to store schedule time blocks and query against them?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-modeling

I am using postgres and wondering how I should store schedule time blocks in a way that allows me to do the following:

If I have a schedule with 3 time blocks:

1. Monday 8am to 12pm
2. Monday 10am to 4pm
3. Thursday 8am to 12pm

And I am trying to find all schedules between Monday and Wednesday that start at 8am.

I am storing the time_blocks as `array`, and I am not sure how to query them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest three columns:

- `dow` - Day of the week as integer or string. Either would work, integer is best for storage and performance. (0 - 6; Sunday is 0)
- `from` - `time` type, time of day
- `to` - `time` type, time of day

Then you can select this way:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "schedule"
WHERE
  -- Mon, Tue, Wed
  "dow" IN (1,2,3) AND
  '08:00:00'::time = "from"
```

You could search for 8am or earlier this way:
`'08:00:00'::time BETWEEN "from" AND "to"`